# passing get url in select case not working

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to pass a variable from a url into a block of code that is loaded into a select statement. the problem that im having is,
it's not grabbing the get url id from the url. if i set id = some number it works, but that's not the aim. the aim is to grab the
id number from the url. i want to load this page into another php page. if i select case 3, it echos try again.
i try printing out the id, but its blank, i also browsed over the link to see what the path is and the id=  . this clearly tells that
its not grabbing or seeing the  $id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['stu']); do i need to pass the variable from one page to another
or am i clearly doing something wrong.

```
$cOption = $_GET['id'];

switch($cOption) {
    case 1:
    echo ' some text';
        break;
    case 2:
    echo ' this page.php';
        break;
    case 3:
    $id = isset($_GET['stu']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT  student.* FROM student WHERE student.email = (SELECT email FROM section WHERE section.user_id = '$id')");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){   echo "try again"; }
    else {  echo 'got it'; 
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Whoops, didn\'t understand that option: <i>'.$cOption.'</i>';
}
```

?>

html page

```
        <div style="width:466px; height:30px">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="show1" href="show.php?id=book">1</a></li>
                <li>Share: <a id="show3" href="show.php?id=feedbk">2</a></li>
                <li><a id="show4" href="show.php?id=media">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tabcontent" style="width: 431px; padding-top:10px; height:auto">show result</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[isset](http://php.net/isset) will return true or false what you is this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['stu']) ? (int) $_GET['stu'] : 0;
```

If `stu` in not an integer remove the `(int)` and put `$id` through `mysql_real_escape_string` before using `$id` in the sql.

Comment: please explain this, why do you put the ? (int) $_GET['stu'] : 0;

Comment: The column name `user_id` suggests it is an integer, `(int)` [typecasts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) `$_GET['stu']` into an integer. This is to prevent a malicious user inject bad SQL into your SQL query through `$_GET['stu']`. If it is not an integer use `mysql_real_escape_string` **Everything** that a user can edit or change has to be treated as suspicious.

Comment: ok, thanks. and yes stu is field that is loaded into the sql statement. to make myself clearer, i might be doing it wrong so let me tell you what im trying to accomplish, this my help to point me in a better position. im trying to load a php page into a tab. i have three tabs, tab1, tab2, tab3. when i click on tab1 i want to load in a php page with a form of some data. i want the page to load only when i click on the tab1. also the content page of tab1 will be pulling a $var from the url, which in turn points this $var into the sql statment so that the satement queries out the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the whole problem, but you're missing a `}` after `else {  echo 'got it';`